# Error while trying to export a file from SVN

Tags: svn, export

Dear All,
I'm trying to export a file from SVN using the following command

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>svn export http://<SVN_LOCATION>/svn/Project/mail/TestProject/Test.java C:/LocalFolder/SVN_Sync --depth empty
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to perform this.
svn: Can't move 'C:\LocalFolder\tempfile.tmp' to 'C:\LocalFolder\SVN_Sync': Access is den
ied.

I could not find any solution for this problem. Can some one please help me to fix this?

Comment: Is SVN_Sync an folder and existing?

Comment: And if yes are you allowed to write to that folder?

Comment: I've permission to write. I tried manually copying the temp file. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the name of the file.

> svn export http:///svn/Project/mail/TestProject/Test.java C:/LocalFolder/SVN_Sync/Test.java --depth empty